# How to show *terminal* buffers in C-x C-b menu

Tags: buffers, multi-term

Currently, buffers with ***names like this*** do not bloat my `C-x C-b` menu, but now that I'm using `multi-term` it's important to be able to see these buffers and be able to select them (only the ones with terminal emulators preferably, but it is ok if others like *scratch* or *messages* show up).

I'm using this to invoke the buffer menu:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'bs-show)
```

Really I don'n know how to engage this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for `bs-mode` says that <kbd>a</kbd> toggles all buffers, and <kbd>+</kbd> then marks an entry to display in both views.

If that's insufficient I can also see the variable `bs-must-always-show-regexp`

Or you can add or edit a configuration in `bs-configurations`, which you can select via <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd>.